# BASH - Check that it is not running the same script

Tags: bash

I have a script /root/data/myscript

and when I run /root/data/myscript

I do not know how to determine if you have one running

does anyone know?

I tried

```
if [[ "$(pidof -x /root/data/myscript | wc -w)" > "1" ]]
then echo "This script is already running!"
fi
```

thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807876/shell-script-execution-check-if-it-is-already-running-or-not    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927091/how-to-check-in-a-bash-script-if-something-is-running-and-exit-if-it-is

Comment: look these two questions. I thinks yours is same with these

Comment: Thank. It is not for me right solution. Control must be from that file /root/data/myscript

Comment: Do you want a generic solution or something that can work for `myscript`?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
if [[ "$(pgrep myscript)" ]]
then echo "This script is already running!"
fi
```

Comment: It is wrong :-( Condition will be satisfied Whenever. Controls the startup of the same file...

Answer (score 0):

This could work to check whether the script is already running or not.

```
if [[ "$(ps -ef | grep "/root/data/myscript" | grep -v "grep")" ]] ; then 
echo "This script is already running!"
fi
```

Try this one.