# How do I make sure my bash script isn't already running?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script I want to run every 5 minutes from cron... but there's a chance the previous run of the script isn't done yet... in this case, i want the new run to just exit. I don't want to rely on just a lock file in /tmp.. I want to make sure sure the process is actually running before i honor the lock file (or whatever)...

Here is what I have stolen from the internet so far... how do i smarten it up a bit? or is there a completely different way that's better?

```
if [ -f /tmp/mylockFile ] ; then
  echo 'Script is still running'
else
  echo 1 > /tmp/mylockFile
  /* Do some stuff */
  rm -f /tmp/mylockFile
fi
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quick-and-dirty way to ensure only one instance of a shell script is running at a time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185451/quick-and-dirty-way-to-ensure-only-one-instance-of-a-shell-script-is-running-at)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
# Use a lockfile containing the pid of the running process
# If script crashes and leaves lockfile around, it will have a different pid so
# will not prevent script running again.
# 
lf=/tmp/pidLockFile
# create empty lock file if none exists
cat /dev/null >> $lf
read lastPID < $lf
# if lastPID is not null and a process with that pid exists , exit
[ ! -z "$lastPID" -a -d /proc/$lastPID ] && exit
echo not running
# save my pid in the lock file
echo $$ > $lf
# sleep just to make testing easier
sleep 5
```

There is at least one race condition in this script. Don't use it for a life support system, lol. But it should work fine for your example, because your environment doesn't start two scripts simultaneously. There are lots of ways to use more atomic locks, but they generally depend on having a particular thing optionally installed, or work differently on NFS, etc...

Comment: Why `cat /dev/null >> $lf` instead of `touch $lf`? Why `sleep` when there's no loop?

Comment: `touch(1)` is good too. The sleep is just for demonstration, to make my script fragment testable on its own.

Comment: (That is, the pid will vanish as soon as that script ends)

Answer (score 9):

You might want to have a look at the man page for the `flock` command, if you're lucky enough to get it on your distribution.

```
NAME
       flock - Manage locks from shell scripts
SYNOPSIS
       flock [-sxon] [-w timeout] lockfile [-c] command...
```

Comment: This solution avoids the race condition between the checking and the obtaining of the lock most cleanly, unlike some other suggested solutions.  If you have 'flock(1)' (which comes with util-linux in debian/Ubuntu etc) definitely use it. For the OP use case, you need a short timeout (e.g. -w 1). If the command is already running, flock will give up after 1 sec, and will not run the command, otherwise, it will obtain the lock and start the command.

Comment: Instead of using `-w 1` to timeout and exit after 1 second, the OP could use `-n, --nb, --nonblock Fail (with an exit code of 1) rather than wait if the lock cannot be immediately acquired.` See example in my answer which was sadly added way after this topic was active.

Answer (score 8):

Never use a lock *file* always use a lock *directory*.
In your specific case, it's not so important because the start of the script is scheduled in 5min intervals. But if you ever reuse this code for a webserver cgi-script you are toast.

```
if mkdir /tmp/my_lock_dir 2>/dev/null
then
   echo "running now the script"
   sleep 10
   rmdir /tmp/my_lock_dir
fi
```

This has a problem if you have a stale lock, means the lock is there but no associated process. Your cron will never run.

Why use a directory? Because mkdir is an atomic operation. Only one process at a time can create a directory, all other processes get an error. This even works across shared filesystems and probably even between different OS types.

Comment: Lock files don't work across NFS -- which is common in shared hosting.  We often use lock directories for the same reason.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to check the process's existence, just look at the output of

`ps aux | grep your_script_name`

If it's there, it's not dead...

As pointed out in the comments and other answers, using the PID stored in the lockfile is much safer and is the standard approach most apps take. I just do this because it's convenient and I almost never see the corner cases (e.g. editing the file when the `cron` executes) in practice.

Comment: In addition, you can store the PID of the current BASH process in that lock file.  BASH provides a variable '$$' (minus the quotes) that gives that number.  See here: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html for some of those variables

Comment: -1 What if "emacs your_script_name" is one of the processes running?

Comment: You're both absolutely right. The PID stored in the file would be a much better way to go. I just tend to do it this way because I'm lazy, my scripts aren't mission-critical, and it usually works (pretty rare that I would actually be editing the script when the cron executes).

Answer (score 4):

Store your pid in `mylockFile`.  When you need to check, look up ps for the process with the pid you read from file.  If it exists, your script is running.

Answer (score 3):

If you use a lockfile, you should make sure that the lockfile is always removed. You can do this with 'trap':

```
if ( set -o noclobber; echo "locked" > "$lockfile") 2> /dev/null; then
  trap 'rm -f "$lockfile"; exit $?' INT TERM EXIT
  echo "Locking succeeded" >&2
  rm -f "$lockfile"
else
  echo "Lock failed - exit" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

The noclobber option makes the creation of lockfile atomic, like using a directory.

Answer (score 3):

As a one-liner and if you do not want to use a lockfile (e.g. b/c/ of a read only filesystem, etc)

```
test "$(pidof -x $(basename $0))" != $$ && exit
```

It checks that the full list of PID that bear the name of your script is equal to the current PID. The "-x" also checks for the name of shell scripts.

Bash makes it even shorter and faster:

```
[[ "$(pidof -x $(basename $0))" != $$ ]] && exit
```

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, you might want to be able to distinguish between who is running the script and allow some concurrency but not all. In that case, you can use per-user, per-tty or cron-specific locks.

You can use environment variables such as $USER or the output of a program such as `tty` to create the filename. For `cron`, you can set a variable in the `crontab` file and test for it in your script.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this one:

```
pgrep -f "/bin/\w*sh .*scriptname" | grep -vq $$ && exit
```

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to solve this problem today and I came up with the below:

```
COMMAND_LINE="$0 $*"
JOBS=$(SUBSHELL_PID=$BASHPID; ps axo pid,command | grep "${COMMAND_LINE}" | grep -v $$ | g    rep -v ${SUBSHELL_PID} | grep -v grep)
if [[ -z "${JOBS}" ]]
then
    # not already running
else
    # already running
fi
```

This relies on `$BASHPID` which contains the PID inside a subshell (`$$` in the subshell is the parent pid). However, this relies on Bash v4 and I needed to run this on OSX which has Bash v3.2.48. I ultimately came up with another solution and it is cleaner:

```
JOBS=$(sh -c "ps axo pid,command | grep \"${COMMAND_LINE}\" | grep -v grep | grep -v $$")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always just:

```
 if ps -e -o cmd | grep scriptname > /dev/null; then 
     exit
 fi
```

But I like the lockfile myself, so I wouldn't do this without the lock file as well.

Comment: Depending on how portable this needs to be, you might need to tweak your ps options, and you might be able to add -q to grep instead of the /dev/null

Comment: Not co-worker proof enough: someone might be running "less scriptname" and that would be enough to prevent the script from running

Comment: mobrule:  Ya, never thought of that, just because I would never do it this way ;-)  The lockfile is better.

Answer (score 0):

Since a socket solution has not yet been mentioned it is worth pointing out that sockets can be used as effective mutexes. Socket creation is an atomic operation, like `mkdir` is as Gunstick pointed out, so a socket is suitable to use as a lock or mutex.

Tim Kay's Perl script 'Solo' is a very small and effective script to make sure only one copy of a script can be run at any one time. It was designed specifically for use with cron jobs, although it works perfectly for other tasks as well and I've used it for non-crob jobs very effectively.

Solo has one advantage over the other techniques mentioned so far in that the check is done outside of the script you only want to run one copy of. If the script is already running then a second instance of that script will never even be started. This is as opposed to isolating a block of code inside the script which is protected by a lock. EDIT: If `flock` is used in a cron job, rather than from inside a script, then you can also use that to prevent a second instance of the script from starting - see example below.

Here's an example of how you might use it with cron:

```
*/5 * * * * solo -port=3801 /path/to/script.sh args args args

# "/path/to/script.sh args args args" is only called if no other instance of
# "/path/to/script.sh" is running, or more accurately if the socket on port 3801
# is not open. Distinct port numbers can be used for different programs so that
# if script_1.sh is running it does not prevent script_2.sh from starting, I've
# used the port range 3801 to 3810 without conflicts. For Linux non-root users 
# the valid port range is 1024 to 65535 (0 to 1023 are reserved for root).

* * * * * solo -port=3802 /path/to/script_1.sh
* * * * * solo -port=3803 /path/to/script_2.sh

# Flock can also be used in cron jobs with a distinct lock path for different
# programs, in the example below script_3.sh will only be started if the one
# started a minute earlier has already finished.

* * * * * flock -n /tmp/path.to.lock -c /path/to/script_3.sh
```

Links:

- Solo web page: http://timkay.com/solo/
- Solo script: http://timkay.com/solo/solo

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185451/quick-and-dirty-way-to-ensure-only-one-instance-of-a-shell-script-is-running-at/23625689#23625689).

I'll just shamelessly copy-paste the solution here, as it is an answer for both questions (I would argue that it's actually a better fit for this question).

## Usage

1. include **sh_lock_functions.sh**
2. init using **sh_lock_init**
3. lock using **sh_acquire_lock**
4. check lock using **sh_check_lock**
5. unlock using **sh_remove_lock**

## Script File

**sh_lock_functions.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

function sh_lock_init {
    sh_lock_scriptName=$(basename $0)
    sh_lock_dir="/tmp/${sh_lock_scriptName}.lock" #lock directory
    sh_lock_file="${sh_lock_dir}/lockPid.txt" #lock file
}

function sh_acquire_lock {
    if mkdir $sh_lock_dir 2>/dev/null; then #check for lock
        echo "$sh_lock_scriptName lock acquired successfully.">&2
        touch $sh_lock_file
        echo $$ > $sh_lock_file # set current pid in lockFile
        return 0
    else
        touch $sh_lock_file
        read sh_lock_lastPID < $sh_lock_file
        if [ ! -z "$sh_lock_lastPID" -a -d /proc/$sh_lock_lastPID ]; then # if lastPID is not null and a process with that pid exists
            echo "$sh_lock_scriptName is already running.">&2
            return 1
        else
            echo "$sh_lock_scriptName stopped during execution, reacquiring lock.">&2
            echo $$ > $sh_lock_file # set current pid in lockFile
            return 2
        fi
    fi
    return 0
}

function sh_check_lock {
    [[ ! -f $sh_lock_file ]] && echo "$sh_lock_scriptName lock file removed.">&2 && return 1
    read sh_lock_lastPID < $sh_lock_file
    [[ $sh_lock_lastPID -ne $$ ]] && echo "$sh_lock_scriptName lock file pid has changed.">&2  && return 2
    echo "$sh_lock_scriptName lock still in place.">&2
    return 0
}

function sh_remove_lock {
    rm -r $sh_lock_dir
}
```

## Usage example

**sh_lock_usage_example.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
. /path/to/sh_lock_functions.sh # load sh lock functions

sh_lock_init || exit $?

sh_acquire_lock
lockStatus=$?
[[ $lockStatus -eq 1 ]] && exit $lockStatus
[[ $lockStatus -eq 2 ]] && echo "lock is set, do some resume from crash procedures";

#monitoring example
cnt=0
while sh_check_lock # loop while lock is in place
do
    echo "$sh_scriptName running (pid $$)"
    sleep 1
    let cnt++
    [[ $cnt -gt 5 ]] && break
done

#remove lock when process finished
sh_remove_lock || exit $?

exit 0
```

## Features

- Uses a combination of file, directory and process id to lock to make sure that the process is not already running
- You can detect if the script stopped before lock removal (eg. process kill, shutdown, error etc.)
- You can check the lock file, and use it to trigger a process shutdown when the lock is missing
- Verbose, outputs error messages for easier debug