# Bash if and or conditionals

Tags: bash

I have a perl script runs in cron and if the script fails to run it leaves behind a lock file to prevent the script to run again.

I'm trying to run a bash script that checks if the process is running and checks to see if a lock file is left behind

if processes is running and lock file exists
exit 0;

if process is not running and lock file exists
rm lockfile. 
exit 0;

if process does not exist and lock file is 'not present' 
exit 0;

I've been checking if the process exists running
ps ax |grep -v grep |grep process.pl

I'm looking for the conditionals in bash that I should be running here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `process.pl` should write its process id into the lockfile, wihch is a common pattern. Then you can write the following code:

```
if [ -f "$lockfile" ]; then
  pid=$(cat "$lockfile")
  if kill -0 "$pid"; then
    : "running normally"
  else
    : "terminated somehow"
    rm -f "$lockfile"
  fi
fi
```

Comment: FYI, in bash, `$(< file)` is a shortcut for `$(cat file)`

Answer (score 2):

`-e` for "file exists":

```
$ if [ -e /etc/passwd ]; then echo "passwords" ; else echo "no passwords" ; fi
passwords
```

`-n` for "length of string is zero" (useful for your `pidof(1)` command).

```
$ F=$(pidof firefox-bin) ; if [ -n "$F" ]; then echo "browser" ; else echo "boring" ; fi
browser
$ F=$(pidof chrome) ; if [ -n "$F" ]; then echo "browser" ; else echo "boring" ; fi
boring
```

(I have `firefox` running, but not `chrome`.)

Answer (score 0):

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715137/the-best-way-to-ensure-only-1-copy-of-bash-script-is-running) for some techniques to make sure only 1 copy of script runs, in bash.

Answer (score 0):

```
pgrep -f process.pl || { [ -f lock.file ] && rm lock.file; }
```