# file locking in R doMC

Tags: r, file-io, parallel-processing, domc

I have some non-parallel code that I would like to parallelize. The code should be embarrassingly parallelizeable except for file operations (multiple files are written to and which file to write is somewhat stochastic and could potentially be the same in different processors). With the `doMC` and `foreach` packages, do I have to handle file locking or is it already handled by the package? I am not tied to `doMC`, I selected it because I will still be making a lot of changes to my code and it seems simple to work with.

Comment: If you open a text file in `append` mode (the default for e.g. `write.table`) multiple files can write at the same time (they don't actually, it's sequential, but you won't generally lose writes that want to write at the same time. If you have lots and lots of jobs across many cores all finishing at the same time then you might lose some results (i found this) so I like to write out to individual files and combine afterwards.

Comment: I should have been more clear, I am writing objects to the files with `save` but I didn't even think to check `help(save)` to see if it handled the locking. It has a parameter `safe=TRUE` that writes to a temporary file and then copies over the original file. This still doesn't exactly provide locking. I am appending to the files, so I would like to in pseudocode `lock(file);load(file);process();save(file);unlock(file)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not found a solution for the general problem. There appears to be a solution in:

[Is there a way to share a lock (e.g. a lock file) between R processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15566536/is-there-a-way-to-share-a-lock-e-g-a-lock-file-between-r-processes)

and this could be considered a duplicate of that.