# Duplicate instances of same linux process

Tags: linux, shell, process, pid

I have a script which does the following w.r.t a linux process-

- To start a process, check if the process is already running. If it is running, then display suitable message and exit. If the process is not running, then start it.
- To stop a process, check if the process is not running. If it is not running, then display suitable message and exit. If the process is running, then stop it.

To summarize, I want to instantiate a process only once. But the issue is when I attempt to instantiate again, it is creating another instance. And the PPID of both instances is 1. Need an expert opinion on this.

Comment: (a) Look in `/etc/rc.d` at the start/stop scripts in there.  (b) How are you detecting whether the program is already running?  You've not shown any code, so we can't tell what you're doing wrong.

Comment: so,you wanna check whether the process is currently running or not ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The best way to ensure only 1 copy of bash script is running?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715137/the-best-way-to-ensure-only-1-copy-of-bash-script-is-running)

Comment: you can check using this  ps ax | grep "process_name$" if process is running or not. if you want to kill the process you can use this pkill -SIGKILL process_name.