# Sub-shell precendence

Tags: bash, io-redirection, subshell

Yesterday I [got some clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21689891/680920) around using `flock` and some simple concepts are becoming clear to me.

My question now is around sub-shells. Take a look at this block

```
(
 flock -s 200 
 # ... commands executed under lock ... 
) 200>/var/lock/mylockfile
```

My understanding is `200>/var/lock/mylockfile` runs *before* `flock -s 200`, yet if I try something like this

```
( echo This is a sub-shell ) command
```

I get an error from BASH

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `command'
```

Introducing a semi-colon

```
( echo This is a sub-shell ); command
```

fixes the error, but causes `command` to run *after* the sub-shell returns.

So I'm wondering how the initial example causes the redirect to run first. Is it something to do with precedence of the `>` over sub-shell `(list)` notation? Looking in the BASH manpage I find

> Operators are evaluated in order of precedence.  Sub-expressions in
>   parentheses are evaluated first and may override the precedence rules
>   above.

Comment: FYI, subshells and lists are syntactically different things -- they have different parser rules, despite using the same character (and thus looking the same to the lexer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`200>/var/lock/mylockfile` is, in this context, information about *how* the subshell should be configured (how its redirection is supposed to be set up). It's not a separate command.

This is true in the same way that

```
echo "foo" >bar.txt
```

...always does the redirection first, as does

```
>bar.txt echo "foo"
```

In neither of these cases does order matter at all.

A subshell is similar in this respect -- it's just a compound command, and like any other command, it can have redirections specified either at its beginning or its end.

Comment: Thanks for this Charles, I presumed I had a fundamental misunderstanding. I'll keep studying.

Comment: By the way, new versions of bash (4.1+) will allocate FDs for you, so you don't have to hardcode numbers. Thus, you can use `{lock_fd}>/path/to/lockfile` and `flock -s "$lock_fd"`

Answer (score 1):

`200>/var/lock/mylock;` only creates `mylock` but that's all.
For instance,

```
$ 200>/var/lock/mylock;
$ echo "hello" >&200
bash: 200: bad file descriptor.
```

doesn't work. If you want this to run, add exec :

```
$ exec 200>/var/lock/mylock;
$ echo "hello" >&200
$ cat /var/lock/mylock
hello
```

Now about subshells : when writing

```
(
   ...
) 200>/var/lock/myfile
```

bash creates a child using `fork()`, then the child redirects 1 to 200 using `dup2`, then parses and executes the code inside `( ... )`.

Thus if you want to create the file before the subshell, a solution is

```
exec 200> /var/lock/file
(
  ...
) >&200
```

Comment: Thank you Edouard, this is also *very* helpful. In looking at the code I've borrowed from yesterday, I was wondering about the use of `exec` for the redirection. I'll study your examples here closely.

Comment: Nice. I suppose I need to just read through the Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide. The manpage alone leaves something to be desired.

Comment: @quickshiftin, I'd strongly suggest the BashGuide instead: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide; we often have to help people unlearn bad habits the ABS taught them in freenode's #bash.

Comment: Thanks Charles, I'll give this a look as well.