# Lock a whole target in a Makefile

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, locking, sh

I have a Makefile with a target that executes multiple system-wide operations (e.g. installing packages), so I want to lock the target in a way that other make processes will wait on that target, thus preventing parallel execution.

I tried using flock as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1985512), but I think the particularities of makefiles are getting in the way.

This is what I have right now:

```
LOCKFILE=/var/lock/makefile.lock
LOCKFD=200

mytarget:
    # make sure to release the lock in any case
    eval "exec $(LOCKFD)>$(LOCKFILE)"; trap "flock -xn $(LOCKFD) && rm -f $(LOCKFILE)" EXIT
    # get exclusive waiting lock
    flock -x $(LOCKFD)
    [regular target operations...]
    # release lock and delete the lock file
    flock -u $(LOCKFD); flock -xn $(LOCKFD) && rm -f $(LOCKFILE)
```

It fails with this error, because the file descriptor 200 is not properly set:

```
$ make mytarget
# make sure to release the lock in any case
eval "exec 200>/var/lock/makefile.lock"; trap "flock -xn 200 && rm -f /var/lock/makefile.lock" EXIT
# get exclusive waiting lock
flock -x 200
flock: 200: Bad file descriptor
Makefile:57: recipe for target 'mytarget' failed
```

There has to be something wrong with the `eval` definition, but I don't see what.

Comment: @shellter All that is explained in the answered I linked to in the question. EXIT is the name of the signal to trap, and looks like `eval` is necessary otherwise `exec` will interpret the fd as a command.

Comment: For future reference, this is why links to external sites are not a good idea. Questions should be standalone. If there is an external source for your information, you can include that, but  you should edit your Q to include the relevant facts. Answer below looks good. Good luck.

Comment: Locking makes thinks difficult, and a target doesn't execute anything. I think you're trying to enforce a non-make way of doing things to which make was designed to provide an alternative. Do you really need locking here? When process A should "wait on" process B, make B create a target after it finishes and make that target a dependency of A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make runs every command line in a new shell. I guess your fd is gone after `eval`. You can use a single command line and separate commands with ";". If you want to split the command line for clarity you need to end all but the last line with "\". See the make manual, [Splitting Recipe Lines](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Splitting-Recipe-Lines.html#Splitting-Recipe-Lines). Or use a shell script.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the link to the make manual! I think your idea of extracting everything into a shell script is going to work best, I will give it a try and report back.

Comment: Extracting everything to a script worked, thanks @rveerd!

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution is using the `.ONESHELL` special target what makes a whole target to run in a single shell, so:

```
.ONESHELL: long_thing

long_thing:
  ...long recipe...
```

Actually, the posix way is to use everything in a `.ONESHELL`, so:

```
.ONESHELL: %
```