# Flag selected rows in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have an agent  i defined a job for that php agent file .but if second agent run after 1 minutes and previous agent work not finished yet .its make a  problem .....
i want to flag selected rows in every agent that if another agent runs new query they haven't interference

how i change this query is the best way is make a field in that table for selected or not ?and update that field ?

```
db::query("SELECT 1000 FROM web-service WHERE `state`= 1 AND `fetch_id`="fetchid"  ")//
```

1-state = 1 is condition for my products

2-i use fetch id to imputation id to each agent what is the best way ?

Comment: I haven't seen this many agents since *Matrix Revolutions*.

Comment: ¿How a select query is affected by another select query? You are not showing all the relevant code

Comment: @Matt its a queue and i connect to a gateway maybe gateway responding late and agent take time for 2 minutes my job run this php file every 1 minutes

Comment: @Alfabravo i described this for matt

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you don't want multiple scripts working on the same rows at the same time. This is known as `contention` and can be solved a number of ways.

One way I have solved this problem in the past is to only run my script if it isn't already running. You can do this through a shell script as defined here: [Shell script: Ensure that script isn't executed if already running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768860/shell-script-ensure-that-script-isnt-executed-if-already-running)

Comment: my friend i want to 2 agnet work at the same time but with that own select products

Comment: You can add a column that flags if the product is "in use", set it after the `SELECT`, then update it once your script finishes.

Comment: hmm is it the best way ? for example can mysql recognize that witch rows selected now and runing ?or the best way is update a field like you for example `in use`?

Comment: Once your `SELECT` is performed, MySQL's job is done. It has no idea what you're doing until the data is manipulated again using an `UPDATE`.