# Running a command only once from a script, even script is executed multiple times

Tags: linux, shell

I need some help. I'm having a script 'Script 1', which will call 'Script 2' to run in background which checks something periodically. But I want the Script 2 to get started only once, even Script 1 is called multiple times. Is there a way to do it?

It would be even more helpful, if someone suggests some commands to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shell script: Ensure that script isn't executed if already running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768860/shell-script-ensure-that-script-isnt-executed-if-already-running)

Comment: Duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185451/quick-and-dirty-way-to-ensure-only-one-instance-of-a-shell-script-is-running-at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can put something like this at the top of `Script2`:

```
if [[ -f /tmp/Script2HasRun ]] ; then
    exit
fi
touch /tmp/Script2HasRun
```

That will stop `Script2` from *ever* running again by using a sentinel file, unless the file is deleted of course, and it probably will be at some point since it's in `/tmp`.

So you probably want to put it somewhere else where it can be better protected.

If you *don't* want to stop it from ever running again, you need some mechanism to delete the sentinel file.

For example, if your intent is to only have one copy running at a time:

```
if [[ -f /tmp/Script2IsRunning ]] ; then
    exit
fi
touch /tmp/Script2IsRunning
# Do whatever you have to do.
rm -f /tmp/Script2IsRunning
```

And keep in mind there's a race condition in there that *could* result in two copies running. There are ways to mitigate that as well by using the content as well as the existence, something like:

```
if [[ -f /tmp/Script2IsRunning ]] ; then
    exit
fi
echo $$ >/tmp/Script2IsRunning
sleep 1
if [[ "$(cat /tmp/Script2IsRunning 2>/dev/null)" != $$ ]] ; then
    exit
fi
# Do whatever you have to do.
rm -f /tmp/Script2IsRunning
```

There are more levels of protection beyond that but they become complex, and I usually find that suffices for most things.

Comment: Thanks a lot paxdiablo. This answer is very useful, and it solves my issue. :)