# Is there any mutex/semaphore mechanism in shell scripts?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, concurrency, semaphore

I'm looking for mutex/semaphore/concurrency mechanism in shell script. 
Consider following situation:
Unless "a" user does not close the shared file, "b" user should not able to open/update it. 
I'm just wondering how to implement mutex, semaphore, critical sections, etc. in shell scripting.

Which is the easiest way to implement locking mechanism [file level] in shell scripting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quick-and-dirty way to ensure only one instance of a shell script is running at a time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185451/quick-and-dirty-way-to-ensure-only-one-instance-of-a-shell-script-is-running-at)

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70/what-unix-commands-can-be-used-as-a-semaphore-lock

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See [BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/045) and [ProcessManagment](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#How_do_I_make_sure_only_one_copy_of_my_script_can_run_at_a_time.3F) for discussions on file locking in Bash.

Tagging your question as shell (only) limits the number of people that can help you. You may want to add unix, ksh, bash.

There are numerous questions/answers on this topic posted here already on S.O.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I didn't say it was a duplicate, the intention was to point a relatively new user to search a little more thoroughly through S.O. I looked for `[bash] file lock` and `[bash] mutex` and found numerous that would add perspective. Good luck.

Answer (score 55):

The [BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/045)
noted by shellter has some good examples. The basic idea, which I'm moving here so the page is self-contained, is to use an operation that both tests and sets at the same time: [mkdir](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?mkdir)

mkdir will fail if the directory exists and will make it if it does not. It's an atomic operation and you can use it like so to do a mutex in your shell script (from the above BashFAQ)

```
# Bourne
lockdir=/tmp/myscript.lock
if mkdir "$lockdir"
then    # directory did not exist, but was created successfully
    echo >&2 "successfully acquired lock: $lockdir"
    # continue script
else    # failed to create the directory, presumably because it already exists
  echo >&2 "cannot acquire lock, giving up on $lockdir"
  exit 0
fi
```

follow the link for more detail on cleanup and other items.

Comment: Isn't the purpose of lock is to hold up till the lock is released. Should this script be like mkdir inside a while loop till it succeeds & once the job is done, the script is suppose to delete the tmp dir ?

Comment: @Pocha that's one way it could work but you might equally want the script to exit with an explanation that's why I came here). If the behaviour described is what you desire it should be easily possible to modify this answer to achieve that.

Answer (score 23):

You can use the `flock` utility to lock a file / use it as a mutex.

Example:

```
#!/bin/sh -eu
#advanced bash stuff not needed
: >> lock #create a file if it doesn't exist
{
flock 3 #lock file by filedescriptor

echo $$ working with lock
sleep 2
echo $$ done with lock

} 3<lock
```

Example usage:

```
./mx & ./mx & ./mx & #will run one at a time cuz of the lock
```

(

In reply to [massimo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471232/massimo)'s point:

If you don't want to hardcode a filedecriptor number (it should rarely be a problem if you aren't hardcoding 0, 1, or 2, but anyway), then in bash
(but not in a POSIX only shell) you can have the system pick a fd for you with:

```
{
flock $fd
#...
} {fd}<lock
```

)

Comment: `flock` (exclusive locks) itself is advanced. ;-)

Comment: terrible suggestion, a constant file descriptor!

Comment: @Massimo Thanks for pointing that out. I've addressed your point in an edit.

Comment: Nice catch!  30 years in bash and you'll never stop to learn new very useful stuff.  Note that this needs [bash 4.1](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashchanges) and above.  With `local -n` (bash 4.3) we get the full power of everything: `{var[sub]}<file`, which can be done as well as: `x() { local -n a="$1" b="$2" c="$3"; exec {a}<&0 {b}>&1 {c}>&2; }` then `declare -A A; x "A[t1]" "A[t2]" "A[t3]"`, but it can even do something like `{!var}<file` which isn't in bash: `x=a1 y=a2 z=a3; x "$x" "$y" "$z"`

Comment: Can someone explain the ```: >> lock``` syntax? Is it creating a file called "lock", or is it a "here document" name only? If it's on the filesystem then perhaps it should be in /tmp instead of whatever the current directory is but I've tested the script and it doesnt seem to create a file so I am bewildered how this bash syntax works but flock is simple enough.

Comment: @guru_florida `: >> lock` uses the :/true do-nothing-successfully command and the `>> lock` (append or create) redirection to create a file named lock unless it already exists.
It's just a demonstration of the mechanism. Sure you'd normally want your lock file somewhere else than in whatever the current directory happens to be. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You will want to prevent constant polling, and use an **interruption** like mechanism instead.

For that use a **file in memory** (run directory), and **wait it** to be changed by another process:

```
mutex="/run/user/$(id -u)/mutex"

waitMutex () {
    tail --follow --lines=0 "${mutex}" |
    head -n1 >/dev/null
    echo > "${mutex}"
}
```

Comment: This solution is specific to a Linux running systemd

Answer (score 0):

I needed a mutex for a bash function, and I am doing

```
mkdir /tmp/nice_exit || return 0
```

At the beginning of the function and then at the end of the function, I am doing

```
rm -rf /tmp/nice_exit
```

Comment: make sure to add a trap to eventually remove it when it stop.