# Waiting for sourced bash script to finish before running it again

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, queue

I have 2 bash scripts..

The first one (begin.sh) is receiving variables from an external PHP script via SSH2, (not visible in this script as they are dynamic) :

But they look something like this :

```
 $1 = myfile.mp3
 $2 = artwork.jpg
 $3 = my title - my artist
```

Here is the first script (begin.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

. ./process.sh
```

And here is the second (process.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

wget -O /root/incoming/shows/$1 http://remoteserver.com/files/$1;

exec lame --decode /root/incoming/shows/$1 - | /root/incoming/stereo_tool_cmd_64 - - -s /usr/incoming/settings/settings.sts | lame -b 128 - /root/incoming/processing/$1;

wait

mv /root/incoming/processing/$1 /var/www/html/processed/$1;

#Send Email when process is complete

recipients="somebody@somewhere.com"
subject="Podcast Submission"
from="somebodyelse@somewhere.com"
importLink="http://thisserveraddress.com/processed/$1"
artwork="http://anotherserver.com/podcast-art/$2"

message_txt=$(echo -e "A new podcast has been submitted.\n\nTitle : $3\n\nImport : $importLink")

/usr/sbin/sendmail "$recipients" << EOF
subject:$subject
from:$from

$message_txt
EOF
```

The process in the script above is time consuming (takes about 8 minutes to complete) and is very processor intensive (uses about 50% CPU), so I only want to run one of these processes at a time. The trouble is, the entire process can be executed remotely at any time by multiple users. So I need to find a way of running these jobs serially in the order that they come in.

I thought sourcing the process script would effectively queue the job's, but it doesn't. If the script is executed again while it's already running nothing happens.

Any suggestions?

Further explanation of what the process.sh script is doing for clarity....

First the host downloads the mp3 file from remoteserver.com

Then it takes the downloaded mp3 file and uses lame to decode it to wav, then another app performs a whole bunch of audio processing on the file after which it re-encodes it back to mp3.

When that's done it moves the new mp3 file to a publicly accessible folder.

Once that's done it sends an email to inform that all this has taken place, and outlines the various links where everything can be downloaded from.

Comment: You need multiple *independent* executions of `begin.sh` to not run `process.sh` if any *other* instance of `process.sh` is running?

Comment: @EtanReisner Kind of,  I need begin.sh to queue the jobs. I thought by sourcing the process script it would wait for the current process to finish and then start the new one, but it isn't. Like I mentioned above, if begin.sh is executed while process.sh is already running it's just ignored and the new process is never run.

Comment: Sourcing the script like that will cause `begin.sh` to wait for it to finish. A second run of `begin.sh` will know nothing about the first run though and will start its own `process.sh` run. The `exec` on that second line isn't doing anything for you that I can tell and you don't need `wait` unless you've run something in the background (with `&`). If you add `set -x` to the top of `begin.sh` and run it twice what output do you get from the second run?

Comment: @EtanReisner thanks I've removed the  **exec**  and **wait** from process.sh. I've also added  **set -x** to **begin.sh**. Now it's running both processes at the same time, exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Right. So the problem is back to needing distinct `begin.sh` processes to know about one another. That's a standard sort of problem. Solutions mostly involve some sort of lockfile or similar mechanism. Or inverting the problem to a job queue submission process.

Comment: @EtanReisner ahh ok. Are there any resources you could point me to that might help me get this done please? I don't even know what to look for other than how I've asked the main question here.

Answer (score 2):

The lock principle could be as follow :
When your script starts, the first thing it does is creating an empty script.lock file in its working folder.
And when it finishes it deletes the script.lock file.
*EDIT : Even better, you can create a script.lock DIRECTORY with mkdir, as sugested by Dror Cohen in his comment*

That's the general idea.
In order to work it in fact needs to really start only if there is no current script.lock that exists. If it does, it instead creates a new file containing the parameter of the call in a /queue/ folder.

So in the end you would have a begin.sh that would be like :

First check if script.lock exists.
- If it does, then write a new file in /queue/ and stop
- If not, create script.lock and proceed

In the very end of the script, it checks if there are any files in the /queue/ folder.
- If there are none, it deletes the script.lock and stops
- If there is a file in /queue/, it takes the older one, deletes it and starts itself again with the parameters saved in the file.

Comment: file checking is not atomic. You should fix your answer to use directory checking instead see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10197327/937)

Comment: Thanks I never realized that. It would definitely matter in timing-critical situations :)

Comment: @CCH that sounds like exactly what I need. I'm trying to implement the solution in the post that Dror linked to, but I don't know how to do the last thing you mentioned, deletes lock and stops etc... Could you show me a working example please? I'm a bit out of my depth here. Also I still don't understand how the queue system will work.

Comment: Actually after reading your original answer a few times I do understand the concept completely, but have no idea of how to implement it. Any help would be most welcome, I'm still learning here :)

Comment: I understand you found out how to do the first part in the begin.sh. For the last part, the best way to do it would be to do exactly the same thing at the end of the process.sh but using rmdir instead of mkdir. This way you could leverage the use of the lock directory by using it as the queue folder too. If you post what you did so far I could point you to the right direction.