# How a program in C++ can interface with shell scripts in Linux by using 'system' variables?

Tags: c++, linux, shell, environment-variables

I have a shell script running on Linux that essentially takes a photo with a Webcam at intervals of 30s and stores the result in a directory, replacing the old image by overwriting it.

This photo is then read by a program written in C++, but once it is executed asynchronously to the script, I would like to use a semaphore in that script so that when I was about to update a new photo (say 5 sec before), the script indicates in this flag the unavailability of the picture for access to any other program.

The first thing that came to my mind was the script simply writing this information in a text file and the C++ program reads it back to know the status, but that struck me as a rough solution.

Another thing I thought, it was the C++ program itself to instantiate the script at 30s intervals, by using the command `exec("./<script>.sh")` but since this program is not always running, wont work.

So, I wonder how to use some kind of "dynamic" system variable (if it exists), something that acts as a RAM, so that I can use it as a flag where the script indicates some status, and the program then reads it.

It is possible ?

Comment: Maybe related: [What Unix commands can be used as a semaphore/lock?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/70/56041) and [Is there any mutex/semaphore mechanism in shell scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6870221/608639)

Comment: I have to admit that the questions that you have indicated have been posed in a more succinct and clear way, but I confess that I did not understand exactly what the 'mechanism' behind those solutions is. Can you tell me which keyword I should be looking for?

Comment: Have you tried named FIFOs?

Comment: Why don't you just delete the old picture in advance of storing the new one?

Comment: @lorro, Sorry, could you elaborate ? If you are referring to pipes, do not solve the question, as said, both the Script and the Executable should work independently, not chained. Anyway, my intend is really to know how to use a dynamic system variable, if exists (I mean, not something that keeps stored after reboot)

Comment: @ypnos, I'm still searching for a way to enable talking between different instances running in parallel

Comment: You need a named pipe. It has a temporary anchor in the filesystem that both processes can open to communicate.

Comment: Ok, but if another script make use of the FIFO, wouldn't it fall into the same queue ?  --EDIT--  Ok, I can create individuals pipes, seems like solved the question

Comment: Looking better, FIFOSs only solve part of the problem; The issue is: How a C++ program could read it ? As far as I know, the "exec()" command just instantiate the scipt, but how could I collect the result form it ?

Comment: How about using [shared memory](https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/C/node27.html)?

Comment: Shared memory seems promising, but the implementation seemed quite complex, I thought such interfacing were simplest; thanks anyway, I'll have a look. By the way, it is still a mistery how to interface with Linux, most examples concerns on interfacing two executables, not with a shell script.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above tips, I got the solution based on 'named pipes' approach. What lies behind this is that FIFOs are essentially treated by the operacional system as 'files', so they can be manipulated with the same standard system libraries that are already available. Just sharing the CPP code used for testing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/stat.h>

#define FIFO_FILE       "MYFIFO"

int main(void)
{
        FILE *fp;
        char readbuf[80];
        int StrCnt = 0 ;

        /* Create the FIFO if it does not exist */
        umask(0);
        mknod(FIFO_FILE, S_IFIFO|0666, 0);

        while(1)
        {
                fp = fopen(FIFO_FILE, "r");
                if ( fp > 0 )
                {
                    fgets(readbuf, 80, fp);
                    printf("Received %d\th string : %s\n", StrCnt++ , readbuf);
                    fclose(fp);
                    // remove(FIFO_FILE);
                    rewind(fp);
                }
        }

        return(0);
}
```

I can put values to MYFIFO with e the following command:

```
echo "abcde12345" > MYFIFO
```

And **ls -al** command shows FIFO content, 10 characters + 1 null character, if code not running:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 esp8266 esp8266    11 10 22 16:10 MYFIFO
```

Whereas if the code is running, it empties the buffer (above function **rewind()**):

```
prw-rw-rw- 1 esp8266 esp8266     0 10 22 16:12 MYFIFO
```