# Create a local lock given a unique name, such as a filepath

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, locking, mutex

I have a shell script, something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e;
try-once-to-get-lock $(pwd) # try to get lock 
start-process  # only if lock acquired, start the desired process
```

I am looking for a way to implement the `try-once-to-get-lock` process - I want to pass it some unique value - the easiest unique value to use would simply be the filepath of the script itself, or the pwd.

Does anyone know if there is some built in tool that I can use on *nix systems to do this? If not, how can I implement this? I'd like to avoid filesystem locks if possible, and perhaps use ports instead.

Answer (score 1):

This question has already be answered several times on SO. See v.gr. [Is there any mutex/semaphore mechanism in shell scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870221/is-there-any-mutex-semaphore-mechanism-in-shell-scripts)

```
#!/bin/bash

lockdir=/tmp/myscript.lock
if mkdir "$lockdir"
then    # directory did not exist, but was created successfully
    echo >&2 "successfully acquired lock: $lockdir"
    # continue script
else    # failed to create the directory, presumably because it already exists
  echo >&2 "cannot acquire lock, giving up on $lockdir"
  exit 0
fi
```

Comment: yep, but this script would then have to delete the lock on exit, that's more code. I am trying to create a library that can do this in one line, proving to be harder than I thought.

Comment: just trying to get something to work w/o using polling

Comment: here is the solution that I have: https://github.com/ORESoftware/quicklock