# Mutex mechanism shared by bash script & C++

Tags: c++, bash, locking, mutex, semaphore

I have several processes, written in C++, accessing to a critical section (read/write a file) and this access is controlled by a mutex. So far everything has gone well, but now I have to redesign my platform and there is a bash script that also has to read/write the file. Is there any library/command that implements a mutex/semaphore/lock mechanism and can be used in both bash scripts and C++?

When I had to work with mutex in bash scripts, I used to create a directory with mkdir -> [Is there any mutex/semaphore mechanism in shell scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870221/is-there-any-mutex-semaphore-mechanism-in-shell-scripts) but I am not very sure what to do in this case.

Comment: Brainstorm idea : Write a C++ executable that opens a pipe.  Start it in your script. From within the executable you read from the pipe and can use all your file writing code including mutex. Then from the script you can write data to the pipe and the exe will the synchronization. (Or make it a deamon/service and let all your existing code use it to really have one synchronization point)

Comment: If you're on a system with [`flock(1)`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/flock.1.html) installed, you can use it in shell and [`flock(2)`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html) in C++ to synchronize things with file locks.