# Is mkdir() atomic with AWS Elastic Block Storage as it is on local POXIS filesystems?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, posix

On my local machine I can do `mkdir` and trust that this operation is atomic. I can thus use it as a lock. Can I similarly use `mkdir` on an EC2 instance with EBS attached and have it be atomic?

For further context, I am thinking of a situation where I have multiple Kubernetes Pods running on a Kubernetes Node with one `persistentVolume` (AWS EBS) between them. If one of these pods is looking to get exclusive access to a folder in this volume, can it do so? The pods are sharing read-only data, but I to trigger an `aws s3 sync` only once per week, not once-per-pod-per-week.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since EBS is not a filesystem...

> Amazon Elastic Block Store (Amazon EBS) provides block level storage volumes for use with EC2 instances.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AmazonEBS.html

...there is no direct answer to the question, because it isn't the correct question.  EBS -- as a block device -- is not responsible for or even aware of the actual filesystem operations or its guarantees.

tl;dr: If `mkdir()` is atomic in the filesystem you are using, then it will still be atomic if that filesystem is on an EBS volume.

Whether using `mkdir()` for locking is a good practice is a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7208447/1695906).