# Am I right about the logic of semaphores?

Tags: process, operating-system, semaphore

This is what I understood about counting semaphores

```
P1 enters critical state 
calls wait()
wait()
{
semaphore--;
if (semaphore<=0)
block;
else
execute the c.s
after execution in c.s calls signal();
}
signal()
{
semaphore++;
If(blocked process exists)
allow first process that is waiting and P1 leaves c.s
}
```

If I am correct then tell me what happens in the case of binary semaphore that can have only 1 and 0 as values. Or is the implementation of binary semaphore different from this?

Answer (score 1):

A few things here :

First try to understand what a semaphore is built to do. Constructs like semaphores are built to help achieve concurrency in programs. Ask yourself - what is it that you want to achieve? Synchronization? Mutual exclusion? Both?

Depending on the answer to that question, the way you use your semaphore will completely change. Understanding the *fundamentals* of what a semaphore does is vital to understanding the difference between a binary and counting semaphore.

I've explained the difference between a binary/counting semaphore in detail here, this will be useful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22582997/2112500
Go through this completely, slowly, step by step, and make sure you understand the fundamentals. Your code above, while telling me that you've understood (to a limited extent) what happens *inside* a semaphore, doesn't necessarily tell me that you know how to use one.

for example, in this bit of pseudo code :

```
else
execute the c.s
after execution in c.s calls signal();
```

You're signalling from inside the wait - that's not quite going to work the way you want it to.

And again, here : 
`allow first process that is waiting and P1 leaves c.s`
I don't think you quite grasp where the semaphore ends, and its use in a thread begins. I would suggest starting with that link above. Then proceed to try and use semaphores in some simple programs to achieve synchronization and mutual exclusion.