# Semaphores/Creating a Critical Section

Tags: concurrency, critical-section, mutual-exclusion

How can you use a semaphore to create a special critical section that allows two threads to be executing inside instead of the usual one thread?

Comment: Conceptually or for a specific language?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898022/differnce-between-counting-and-binary-semaphores.

Answer (score 0):

In pseudocode it looks like so:

```
s = Semaphore(2)    # max 2 possible threads accessing the critical section
```

Each thread then uses the semaphore to serialize access:

```
s.decrement()    # may block 
    # enter critical section
s.increment()
```

Useful resource is: [The Little Book of Semaphores](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~kishore/papers/semaphores.pdf)