# Bash program in cron that runs everytime the program is terminated

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, cron, web-scraping

I want to set a cron job in ubuntu with this job

I have a python webscraping program which needs to be scrapped continuously after the program is terminated. In other words the flow is like this

```
If program is terminated, set the cron job again (until infinity in cron's method)

something like * * * * * /python.py (but only when the python.py is terminated/finished)
```

Can someone guide me to write a bash program that does this job? The program is python.py

thanks

Comment: some other ideas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185451/quick-and-dirty-way-to-ensure-only-one-instance-of-a-shell-script-is-running-at

Answer (score 1):

when the program runs, write a temp file somewhere, and make sure this file is deleted when the program terminates.

then test if the file exists every time the program runs. exit if it's there.

run.sh

```
TMP_FILE=/tmp/i_am_running
[ -f $TMP_FILE ] && exit
touch $TMP_FILE
./python.py
rm $TMP_FILE
```

in your crontab, call this `run.sh` instead of `python.py`.

keep in mind that if the script exits early (get killed, etc) and the tmp file stays in the file system, it won't run python.py again. there's things you can do to prevent or detect situations like that too.

Comment: Create TMP_FILE using mktemp: TMP_FILE=$(mktemp -t myapp.XXX) echo $TMP_FILE /tmp/myapp.025 and use trap clean EXIT to cleanup temporary files: clean() { rm $TMP_FILE; }; trap clean EXIT

Comment: so if the program gets crashed or something, then will it effect the results of the program? its actually scrapping data from a website

Comment: is there any simpler method as an alternative?

Comment: Use trap to handle early exists/crashes and here you have some other ideas - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185451/quick-and-dirty-way-to-ensure-only-one-instance-of-a-shell-script-is-running-at