# How to avoid shell script execulated by multi thread

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I use python multi threading to execulate a shell script, but for some reason, this shell script can't execulate by multi thread, I want make this script avoid multi thread for foolproof, Is any way can do?

thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37303133/2836621

Comment: *this shell script can't execulate by multi thread* - what happened?  Does it give an error message, or what?  Please define "can't execute".  How are you executing the script from python?  In python, are you aware of the GIL?  http://www.dabeaz.com/python/UnderstandingGIL.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a mutex. Say, create in the script check if a file is created (e.g. in /temp). If file exists, exit. If not, create it and do useful actions. In the end delete the file.