# Check if double process execution is real

Tags: linux, bash

I created a script to verify if a scheduled process is already running and in that case I block the execution showing a message "script is already running". The problem is that I inserted these lines of code

```
scriptToVerify="send_xxxx.sh ${1} ${2}";
num_proc=`ps auxww | grep "$scriptToVerify" | grep -v $$ | grep -v grep | awk /./ | /usr/bin/wc -l`;

if [ $num_proc -gt 1 ];
then
    sl_log "---------------------------Warning---------------------------"
    sl_log "$scriptToVerify Already running"
    exit 0;
fi
```

in a large number of scripts (every script is scheduled, sometimes at the same time). I have tried different solutions: using a flock instruction, using a lockfile, but everytime (even the instructions I wrote above) my code works for a few weeks and then starts to report a "script already running" also it isn't true.

Unfortunately I can't manage the scheduler, so how can I modify my script in order to verify if a process is actually running?

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/37303133/2836621

Comment: I don't think "grep -v $$" is good idea. what happens when the script is running in pid = 12. and the script to verify is runnig in pid = 1234 ?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I already did it. Is one of the first thread I've seen

Comment: What are the parameters `$1` and `$2`? Could they contain any special symbols like `*`, `+`, `?`, `.` which would then be interpreted by grep and could lead to false matches?

Comment: @Socowi no, they are two parameters and they are string or int

Comment: A string can contain the symbol `*`. Or did you mean both of these parameters can only assume the literal values "`string`" and "`int`"? The latter would be very strange.

Comment: @Socowi no, they are defined like this: /folder1/folder2/folder3/script.sh icbp 8

Answer (score 1):

Using `ps ... | grep ... | grep -v ... | grep -v grep | ...` to match process by its name (or command line) is fraught with problems (like the `$$` matching also part of PID as mentioned in one of the comments), using [`pgrep(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pgrep.1.html) in this case should be much easier and give you just what you need.

You do not have to worry about its output either (even though it can `-c` count matches) and instead just use the fact it'll return `0` if anything matched and `1` otherwise. Use `-f` in this case to match against the full command line and not just process name.

```
if pgrep -f "${scriptToVerify}" >/dev/null; then
    echo "'${scriptToVerify}' already running"
fi
```

You can also make it a bit more verbose if you still got accidental unwanted matches (note: some process could get terminated between call to `pgrep` and `ps` that follows):

```
matched_pids=$(pgrep -f "${scriptToVerify}")
if [[ -n "${matched_pids}" ]]; then
    echo "Already running:"
    ps -o pid,cmd -p ${matched_pids}
fi
```

You can also make sure pattern does not accidentally match unwanted strings (processes), and for instance use `pgrep -f "${scriptToVerify}\$"` of not other arguments follow or even `pgrep -f "^${scriptToVerify}\$"` if `scriptToVerify` is a complete match, or `pgrep -f "(^|\\<)${scriptToVerify}\$"` perhaps the value starting with script basename and all the arguments are expected to be a match.

Comment: Ideally you would also use `pgrep`'s `-x` option and quote special symbols like `*` inside the variable `scriptToVerify`.