# Linux command execution rate limiting

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I have a Linux command that can be called by another application multiple times (in quick succession) with different parameters. The problem is, if the command gets executed in too quick of succession, the function that it performs will not work properly.

What I’m looking for is some simple way to ensure that each call to the command will be properly delayed/spaced (by a couple milliseconds) from each other.

Order of execution does not matter in this case and I have no control over how the application makes the calls.

**Edit**: The command being called is used to transmit an RF signal on a Raspberry Pi. As such, the command execution must be exclusive (no concurrency) with an additional delay between executions to prevent the receivers from misreading the signals.

Comment: you can read about `sleep` command in Linux...

Comment: Does that work when the calls to the command are in parallel?

Comment: Would this help you ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/185473/12396017

Comment: Not precisely, since I want it to block until other calls complete, but it looks like that would be a quick fix.

Comment: Do you need to implement this only at your end, or can  you make changes to the caller?

Comment: I cannot make changes to the caller.

Comment: Can you provide few more details about the process (or show simplified version). There are few options to limit concurrent execution (vs allowing single execution using the flock).

Comment: I added more info to the question. In reality, what I needed was single execution, so flock was the right fix. I will keep your answer in mind, however, if I ever need more than single execution in a similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone with the same problem, this worked for me: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/408934/how-to-serialize-command-execution-on-linux

```sh
CMD="<some command> && sleep <some delay in seconds>"

flock /tmp/some_lockfile $CMD
```

Answer (score 1):

For a simple concurrency control, which will limit concurrent execution to  instances, consider the following `while` loop (modify as needed).

**Note that the script must be invoked as /path/to/script.sh so that it will find other instances. Starting with 'bash /path/to/script.sh' will require changes!**

```
#! /bin/bash

   # Process identifier.
echo "START $$"
ME=${0##*/}
   # Max number of instances
N=5
   # Sleep while there are more than N instances.
while [[ "$(pgrep -c -x $ME)" -gt "$N" ]] ; do echo Waiting ... ; sleep 1 ; done

   # Execute the job
sleep "$@"
echo "Done $$"
```