# How to lock the folder when the bash script is running inside

Tags: bash, makefile

I have a task flow which can be divided into step_1 and step_2, both running in bash.
step_1 needs run a bash script in folder_a.
when I submit my jobs into multiple hosts, there are multiple threads which will trigger the bash script in folder_a, this will break the function.

I want my jobs run as following :

1. every job's step_1 has to run one by one, otherwise it will break function in the folder_a.
2. every job's step_2 can run parallelly for speed.

How to lock the folder if the bash in folder_a is running and refuse to run for other thread ?
Maybe I can only lock the step_1 bash top script inside folder_a, instead of the folder.

Comment: see https://man.cx/flock or https://man.cx/lockfile

Comment: You can use **GNU Parallel** as a mutex... https://stackoverflow.com/a/37303133/2836621 You can also use **GNU Parallel** to run your jobs in parallel, on multiple hosts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working under a Unix-like system (GNU/Linux, BSD...) you probably have `flock` and you could wrap the critical jobs in `flock` calls:

```
step1_job: | folder_a/.lock
    flock $| command [arguments]

folder_a/.lock:
    touch $@
```

See `man flock` for the details.

Comment: I tested flock, it works for my needs, added flock -x . before the command which needs to be locked for multiple process.  example in my top task shell script :  1. cd folder_a;      2.  flock -x . command_for_step1